# Slider works on JSFiddle, only shows text box when I try it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gefkwqv6/8/ I found this, and when I wanted to implement it myself, it only shows a textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div class="range-slider">
    <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="extra-controls">
    From: <input type="text" class="js-input-from" value="0" readonly/>
    To: <input type="text" class="js-input-to" value="0" readonly/>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/C.js" rel="script"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
    $inputFrom = $(".js-input-from"),
    $inputTo = $(".js-input-to"),
    instance,
    min = 0,
    max = 1000;

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: min,
    max: max,
    from: 100,
    to: 900,
    onStart: updateInputs,
    onChange: updateInputs,
    onFinish: updateInputs
});

function updateInputs (data) {
    $inputFrom.prop("value", data.from);
    $inputTo.prop("value", data.to);
}

instance = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");
```

What am I missing? Do I need to import something else? Because at the moment I'm feeling oblivious that such a simple code won't work

Comment: jsfiddle by default places script inside `window.onload` try doing the same and see

Comment: Did u include ion.rangeSlider.js,ion.rangeSlider.css,ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css in the project

Comment: @Anbarasi that's the thing I forgot! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing some js and css files thease are :

```
ion.rangeSlider.js // js file
ion.rangeSlider.css //css file 
ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css // css file
```